# Widget to toggle "OK Google" detection always on/off

Tags: app-widgets, ok-google

I am looking for a widget which toggles my Nexus 6's option for "OK Google" always listen on/off.

Usually when I am in the car, I need the phone to always listen for "OK Google" and easily turn it on before I get there. After I leave the car, I need to turn it off, because it detects random sounds as the command and never stops listening for noise sounds.

I think such widget does not exists and I do not know if Android exposes API calls for this. I am web developer and I am willing to try to code this widget myself (never tried to code for Android), but I have the will if someone points me to the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: you might wanna look into this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.RSen.Commandr&hl=en

Comment: It's cool indeed, but not really what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: in the above link , there you can find the github repo link where you can find the source code of that project where you can start building your app based on that but before that you need to learn and create basic android apps before directly coding the app you want.

Comment: [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) might be able to do what you're asking.

Comment: Tasker doesn't seem to have this functionality

Answer (score 1):

It's not the best method but if you happen to use [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en) you can make a widget that gets to the Voice Command Preferences (which is just one click away from accessing the detection settings).

1. Long-press on the home screen (with Nova installed)
2. Click Widgets
3. Place an Activities shortcut somewhere on your homescreen.
4. Scroll down to the Google App
5. Choose com.google.android.voicesearch.VoiceSearchPreferences

and you'll at least have a widget that gets you right to the Voice Search Preferences where you can then click on Ok Google detection.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I do not want to change the launcher. I want to use a widget which is independent of the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

What [Nick Ebi](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/114890/nick-ebi) [described for Nova launcher](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/113892/16575) is also possible without switching to Nova (or Apex launcher, which offers the same). You can use [Activity Launcher](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.szalkowski.activitylauncher), an app working independently from the launcher you're using (in fact, it should work with any launcher). Launch that app, and then follow steps 4+5 of Nick's answer, and you will end up with a shortcut on your homescreen. *Activity Launcher* even allows you to edit that shortcut, giving it a custom name and even assign it an icon of your choice.

Again, not a full solution – but an improvement at least.

For a full solution, follow [ND Geek](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/16078/nd-geek)'s advice from the comments on your question, and use [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker). While *Tasker* itself might not have this functionality, there's the [AutoVoice](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autovoice) plugin offering you an "always listening" mode (called "continuous" there). But that doesn't come for free: both have a trial version, though.

Comment: `com.google.android.voicesearch.VoiceSearchPreferences` is opening the first settings screen. Then I have to click **"Ok Google detection"** and switch the **"Always on"** setting. I am looking for direct toggle of this setting. So far this is the closest answer to the solution :)

Comment: @IvanDokov, have you checked the second half of my answer? *AutoVoice* can do that. I've ended up with a widget to toggle "Continuous Mode" on/off. Isn't that what you've asked for? Check out my [collection of Tasker resources](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker), which a.o. also holds a section with "AutoVoice Tutorials".

Comment: To be honest the first time I tried Tasker I got lost and didn't like it. I will try again today :)

Comment: @IvanDokov To be honest, it took me 3 days to figure how it works when I tried it the first time – but on that 3rd day, though I had 4 days of trial left, I immediately bought the license as it really convinced me. Yeah, it might have a steep learning curve – but it's worth it!

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe there is a widget, but you can turn it on/off in the google app under the ok google settings.

Comment: I am aware of this, but I want to use widget for faster usage.